# Base table connection with extension tables

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is it possible to achieve that behaviour.
I have table scheme:

```
Common table:
ID (Primary key)
Hash

DomainModelOne:
ID(same id as in common table, one to one)
Name,
Time,
Card,
etc...

DomainModelTwo:
ID(same id as in common table, one to one)
Color
```

Maybe some more extension table with different columns.

In ef core 7 dbcontext, I need two properties:

```
public DomainModelOne DomainModelOne {get; set;}
public DomainModelTwo DomainModelTwo {get; set;}
```

Domain classes should be inherited from class Common.

```
public class Common
{
public long Id {get; set;}
public string Hash {get; set;}
}
```

In my application I need to forbid to create instance of common class, because it can't be mapped to any domain entity. Based on this idea Common class should be abstract, but as I know ef inheritance strategy can't create independent table for common abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Just make "Common" an abstract class and don't configure it as an EF entity.  It will still be common base class in .NET but EF and your database won't know anything about it.